# Windows7 Lock Desktop icons

Tags: windows-7

I wonder if any windows admin knows a good solution for this.
It does not need to be secure, just for dummy users who deleting/renaming/moving around icons on their desktops.

What I need is that the user cannot:

- Create new icons on the desktop
- Delete any icons from the desktop
- Modify icons on the desktop
- Cannot even move icons on the desktop (they are pre arranged as they should be)

If anyone know 3rd party tools for this please share it!

Thanks!

Comment: Your question seems more suited for our Desktop Q&A site Superuser, but before I'd recommend migrating it over there I'd like to know if you have these Windows 7 workstations on a network joined to a domain.  Is that the case?  If so, we can reword your question to make it a better fit for ServerFault.  Let me know, and welcome to the community.

Answer (score 0):

You would put the icons you want to protect from modification or deletion in the "Public" desktop (replacement for the XP "All Users" profile).

As to not being able to move them, there's an option to lock the icons in place (right click on the desktop and click the option from the context menu).